# jQuery scroll animates up instead of down

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery scroll code which if it contains a `#` then it would scroll to the associated div ID however, some of my links are scrolling up instead of down to the div it should scroll to. Any suggestions why this might happen?

```js
function(e, t, n) {
  "use strict";
  
  var i = {
    init: function() {
      $('[href^="#"]').on("click", function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        e = $(this).attr("href");
        
        // "#" != e && ((e = $(e).offset().top), $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: e + -50 }, 1e3));
        
        "#" != e && ((e = $(e).offset().top), $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: e - 100
        }, 1e3));
      });
    },
  };
  t.exports = i;
}
```

Comment: You will need to add your html to your question. Far easier for us to look at a working demo of your code/problem

Comment: Your code works fine .. you'll need to activate `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the `#` default behavior

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef i activated the preventDefault and it still is scrolling up